# How to improve MERN stack efficiency in terms of speed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, performance, fetch

I have a MERN stack application with multiple routes in App.js file and in each route I need to fetch data from Mongo and render. There are a few collections which I need in all these routes, but since they are different routes whenever they open it will refetch all the data mentioned in its componentdidmount.

Is there any way to make this more efficient and reduce the amount of data fetching from mongo because to be honest, mongo is working very slow and I cannot afford that slow loading in every single route.

I have routes in my App.js like so:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
<Route path="/category/:slug" exact component={Category} />
<Route path="/product/:slug" exact component={SingleProduct} />
```

I first thought of fetching data in App.js and passing it down via props to these route components (I found a way of doing that on google). That way, I would not need to fetch data which is common between these components again and again. But, whenever route change the page will remount basically and app.js will refetch entire data so that is pretty much same as before.

Is there any way of using these components as url params?
Example:

```
localhost:3000?currentpage=home
localhost:3000?currentpage=category&slug=xyz
localhost:3000?currentpage=singleproduct&slug=xyz
```

If yes, how can I achieve this is app.js? Otherwise, how can I make my app more efficient in terms of speed while fetching data from mongo.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need using render instead of component in the Route. Read the documentation bellow to understand better. By rendering your component mounts only once.

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func